How to use sepolia deployed erc-20 token for my project?
I'm new to proper deployment and interaction of tokens on smart contract and I'm unable to understand how to use my erc-20 token(address-0x7E0405b46F427cae024563a358d47455De256adc) in a coinflip game. I wanna transfer some of these erc-20 tokens to my game contract and then another to my friends wallet to try playing.
My game contract is-
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

import "./Error.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/interfaces/IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/vrf/dev/libraries/VRFV2PlusClient.sol";
import "solady/src/utils/ReentrancyGuard.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";

contract CoinFlip is VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus, ReentrancyGuard {
    /* Storage:
     ***********/

    IERC20 public immutable token; // Your ERC-20 token reference
    IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus internal immutable COORDINATOR;
    bytes32 internal immutable KEY_HASH;
    uint256 private immutable SUBSCRIPTION_ID;
    uint16 private constant REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS = 3;
    uint32 private constant CALLBACK_GAS_LIMIT = 1e5;
    uint32 private constant NUM_WORDS = 1;

    uint256 public constant MIN_BET = 10 * 10**18; // Minimum bet in tokens (10 tokens in this example)
    uint256 private contractBalance;

    struct PlayerByAddress {
        uint256 balance;
        uint256 betAmount;
        uint256 betChoice;
        address playerAddress;
        bool betOngoing;
    }

    struct Temp {
        uint256 id;
        uint256 result;
        address playerAddress;
    }

    mapping(address => PlayerByAddress) public playersByAddress;
    mapping(uint256 => Temp) public temps;

    event DepositToContract(address indexed user, uint256 indexed depositAmount, uint256 newBalance);
    event Withdrawal(address player, uint256 amount);
    event NewIdRequest(address indexed player, uint256 requestId);
    event GeneratedRandomNumber(uint256 requestId, uint256 randomNumber);
    event BetResult(address indexed player, bool victory, uint256 amount);
    event ContractBalanceWithdrawn(address indexed owner, uint256 amount);

    constructor(
        address _vrfCoordinator,
        bytes32 _keyHash,
        uint256 _subscriptionId,
        address _tokenAddress
    ) VRFConsumerBaseV2Plus(_vrfCoordinator) {
        COORDINATOR = IVRFCoordinatorV2Plus(_vrfCoordinator);
        KEY_HASH = _keyHash;
        SUBSCRIPTION_ID = _subscriptionId;
        token = IERC20(_tokenAddress); // Set ERC-20 token
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                           // WRITE FUNCTIONS//
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function bet(uint256 _betChoice) public nonReentrant {
        uint256 betAmount = MIN_BET;
        if (_betChoice != 0 && _betChoice != 1) revert CoinFlip__InvalidBetChoice();

        address player = msg.sender;
        PlayerByAddress memory _player = playersByAddress[player];

        if (_player.betOngoing) revert CoinFlip__BetAlreadyOngoing();

        _player.playerAddress = player;
        _player.betChoice = _betChoice;
        _player.betOngoing = true;
        _player.betAmount = betAmount;

        // Transfer the player's tokens to the contract
        require(token.transferFrom(player, address(this), betAmount), "Token transfer failed");
        contractBalance += betAmount;

        playersByAddress[player] = _player;

        uint256 requestId = requestRandomWords();
        temps[requestId].playerAddress = player;
        temps[requestId].id = requestId;

        emit NewIdRequest(player, requestId);
    }

    function withdrawPlayerBalance() public nonReentrant {
        address player = msg.sender;
        if (playersByAddress[player].betOngoing) revert CoinFlip__BetOngoing();
        if (playersByAddress[player].balance == 0) revert CoinFlip__NoFundsToWithdraw();

        uint256 amount = playersByAddress[player].balance;
        delete (playersByAddress[player]);

        // Transfer tokens back to the player
        require(token.transfer(player, amount), "Token transfer failed");

        emit Withdrawal(player, amount);
    }

    function deposit(uint256 amount) public {
        if (amount == 0) revert CoinFlip__InsuffisantAmount();
        require(token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount), "Token transfer failed");
        contractBalance += amount;

        emit DepositToContract(msg.sender, amount, contractBalance);
    }

    /*//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                            VIEW FUNCTIONS
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

    function getPlayerBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return playersByAddress[msg.sender].balance;
    }

    function getContractBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return contractBalance;
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                        //PRIVATE FUNCTIONS//
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function requestRandomWords() private returns (uint256) {
        return
            COORDINATOR.requestRandomWords(
                VRFV2PlusClient.RandomWordsRequest({
                    keyHash: KEY_HASH,
                    subId: SUBSCRIPTION_ID,
                    requestConfirmations: REQUEST_CONFIRMATIONS,
                    callbackGasLimit: CALLBACK_GAS_LIMIT,
                    numWords: NUM_WORDS,
                    extraArgs: VRFV2PlusClient._argsToBytes(VRFV2PlusClient.ExtraArgsV1({ nativePayment: false }))
                })
            );
    }

    function fulfillRandomWords(uint256 _requestId, uint256[] calldata _randomWords) internal override {
        uint256 randomResult = _randomWords[0] % 2;
        temps[_requestId].result = randomResult;

        checkResult(randomResult, _requestId);
        emit GeneratedRandomNumber(_requestId, randomResult);
    }

    function checkResult(uint256 _randomResult, uint256 _requestId) private returns (bool) {
        address player = temps[_requestId].playerAddress;
        bool win = false;
        uint256 amountWon = 0;

        PlayerByAddress memory _player = playersByAddress[player];

        if (_player.betChoice == _randomResult) {
            win = true;
            amountWon = _player.betAmount * 2;
            _player.balance += amountWon;
            contractBalance -= amountWon;
        }

        _player.betAmount = 0;
        _player.betOngoing = false;
        playersByAddress[player] = _player;

        emit BetResult(player, win, amountWon);

        delete (temps[_requestId]);
        return win;
    }

    function withdrawContractBalance() public onlyOwner {
        if (contractBalance == 0) revert CoinFlip__NoFundsToWithdraw();

        uint256 toTransfer = contractBalance;
        contractBalance = 0;

        // Transfer all contract's tokens to the owner
        require(token.transfer(owner(), toTransfer), "Token transfer failed");

        emit ContractBalanceWithdrawn(owner(), toTransfer);
    }
}

also, i'd really appreciate if someone can share any knowledge to this game and possible front end connectivity to this.

Although the question is very broad. I'll try to write the steps.

You'll need a token contract deployed before deploying this game contract, make sure you have the ability to mint the tokens.
You'll pass the deployed token contract address to the constructor of this game contract, while deploying.
Once deployed, you can now send the tokens to your friends wallet etc. by calling the transfer function on the token contract.
Now to call the bet or deposit function in this game contract, you'll need to first approve the amount of tokens to this contract's address. You'll do so by calling the approve function in the token contract by passing this contract's address and the amount.
Once approved, now you can call the bet or deposit function.

I would suggest understanding how things work before directly just writing the code and testing it.
EDIT:
Question - what is the difference between transfer and transferFrom function?
The transfer function is used when an EOA or Smart Contract directly wants to send tokens to any other address. This takes the recipient's address and the amount as arguments and transfers the amount from the caller to the recipient's address.
On the other hand, transferFrom is used to spend someone else's tokens, if allowed by the owner.
The token holder must approve the spender's address and a certain amount of token. Then only the spender will be able to spend the tokens on behalf of the owner. This function takes three parameters, from address, to address, and the amount. It sends the amount token from the from address to the to address

OKOK got it thanks. But what is the difference between transfer and transferFrom function. I'm using the openzeppelin erc20 token maker thingie btw, so thats fine right?

Updated the answer with this query. And yes OZ contracts are best to start with.
